# Converting JavaScript Multi dimension Array into Java Array

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

I am using [HandsOnTable](http://handsontable.com/) to perform some business operation but while saving the form i retrieve data with method

```
handsOnTable.getData();
```

which returns something like (JavaScript Array)

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

but I am not able to figure out a way to convert this into

```
List<List<Integer>>
```

Comment: If the data is a `String` you can use a `JSON` library to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) will do this for you automatically.  I think this will get it done:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]";
java.lang.reflect.Type.Type listOfListsOfIntsType = new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.TypeToken<List<List<Integer>>>(){}.getType();
List<List<Integer>> list = gson.fromJson(json, listOfListsOfIntsType);
```

You can skip the `TypeToken` business if you define a class with a member variable of type `List<List<Integer>>` and just pass that class as the 2nd argument to `fromJson()`.

Comment: Thanks, Exactly What I was Searching. Edited in order to eliminate confusion of which package to import for `Type` and `TypeToken`

Comment: Good edit, thanks.  (I was just auto-importing `Type` in NetBeans yesterday and the dropdown showed me about 50 choices of classes named `Type` to choose from...)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    int[][] dataArray = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    List<List<Integer>> dataList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        List<Integer> tmpList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        dataList.add(tmpList);
        for (int j = 0; j < dataArray[i].length; j++) {
            tmpList.add(dataArray[i][j]);
            System.out.println(dataArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
```